# C# - ListView columns on left side?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

Is there a way to set the columns to be on the left of side of a listview instead of on the top?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Assuming Winforms)

No, I don't think so. But you can use a DatagridView to get that effect.